# ngrok as a service: cannot get logging to work

Tags: windows, logging, service, ngrok

Using ngrok v3.3.0, Windows 10 Pro.

I'm running ngrok as a Windows service and have set logging to log locally to disk (see below).  When I start the service, it does create an empty log file, but I'm not seeing any entries to it.

*Partial ngrok.yml file:*

```
authtoken: xxxxxxxx
version: "2"
region: us
log_level: info
log_format: logfmt
log: logs/ngrok.log
tunnels:
<snip>
```

Looking at the ngrok agent status (//localhost:4040), I'm seeing the same values for logLevel and logFormat as in my config file, but the logTarget value is always stdout.

```
logFormat   logfmt
logLevel    info
logTarget   stdout
```

I was hoping to see (1) some startup info when I start the service and then (2) each request to my web service to be logged, but something must be misconfigured or I'm not understanding how ngrok logging works.

What am I doing wrong?  If you need more information, please let me know.

thanks,
randy